# SQL -- Assigning a bit variable in select statement

Tags: sql

For example:

```
declare @bitHaveRows bit
 select @bitHaveRows = count(*)
   from table
  where (predicate)
```

Are there any functions I can call on this line:

```
select @bitHaveRows = count(*)
```

to assign this bit a value of 0 if there are no rows, or 1 if there are one or more rows?

Comment: What db engine (mysql, oracle, microsoft)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [conversion chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), there's an implicit conversion from int to bit.  But if for some reason that doesn't work:

```
CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks. I was hoping the implicit conversion would work in that context but apparently not.

Answer (score 7):

```
declare @bRowsExist
SELECT @bRowsExist = CAST(count(*) as bit)
FROM yourtable
```

...not sure if it's a better query than the other suggestions

Answer (score 1):

If your database supports it, you can use a CASE statement:

```
declare @bitHaveRows
select @bitHaveRows = case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end
from yourtable
```