# Is there any reason why you cannot select a statement as a bit in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am wondering why the following fails:

```
SELECT price<500 as PriceIsCheap
```

and forces you to do the following:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (price<500) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as PriceIsCheap
```

When, [as per the answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879857/sql-assigning-a-bit-variable-in-select-statement), the [conversion table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) says that an implicit conversion should occur.

Comment: Edit: Changed the example condition because apparently '1=1' as a placeholder makes the question contrived.

Comment: Giving a minimal example of a problem is a good practice, normally - it is quite obvious you don't want `SELECT 1` because then you'd've written exactly that.

Comment: Up until a few versions ago, the `bit` type in SQL Server could not be nullable. Since a comparison can result in TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN, there was no way to represent UNKNOWN. And if you don't consider UNKNOWN to be the same as NULL, there is still no way to represent it.

Comment: @Gabe put this as an answer and I will accept it. It correctly answers the why.

Comment: @Gabe: Nice bit of info (no pun intended). However that still makes no sense. Having a space-efficient bit type is all fine and good, but not having a proper boolean is bullshit. I'm not saying bit should be nullable, but why didn't they then make a new type that is, and takes whopping 2 bits of storage? Especially since such a type obviously exists internally (otherwise, what does `<` return, and what does `CASE` accept?)

Comment: @Amadan it's so odd that the spec mentions functions that return a type that is not declared in the types section of the spec. Compile error much?

Comment: Your second `SELECT` statement returns a value of type `INTEGER` rather than of type `BIT` (not that that's a bad thing...)

Comment: @onedaywhen Very true and great observation but as you've pointed out it's a trivial cast and SQL is smart enough to convert int -> boolean just not backwards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no boolean data type in SQL, `BIT` is kind of a hack, but the main problem is that due to the SQL concept of `NULL` true [boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic) is impossible (for example, what would your query return if `price` was `NULL`?)

Note that I'm not saying that there are not *possible* ways to implement boolean logic that "mostly" work (for example, you could say that `TRUE OR NULL` is `NULL` or whatever) just that the people who designed the SQL standard couldn't decide on The One True Representation for boolean logic (for example, you could also argue that `TRUE OR NULL` is `TRUE`, since `TRUE OR <anything>` is `TRUE`).

The boolean expressions (=, <=, >=, etc) are only valid in certain places (notably, `WHERE` clauses and `CASE` labels) and not in any other place.

Comment: Cool, I wish now that bit can be nullable they'd fix this, because obviously they *have* decided on The One True Representation for boolean logic for the purposes of evaluation. Interestingly, you can't compare booleans - (SELECT CASE WHEN (1=1) = (1=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) fails.

Comment: AFAIC, `TRUE OR NULL` = `TRUE`, not unknown (whatever MS said). http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-logical.html agree with me. Despite SQL not defining it, it is so useful that there is no excuse for any particular implementation not to do it.

Comment: That's an interesting one to note when converting SQL statements between vendors.

Comment: Note that the way it works in MySQL and PostgreSQL *changes the meaning of NULL*. My point is that the argument can be made both ways: make `NULL` work like "UNKNOWN" as MySQL and PostgreSQL do, or make `NULL` work like it does in any other statment, which is what SQL Server does with the `BIT` data type. There are arguments for doing it either way.

Answer (score 3):

Well you'll also find you can't if you have a bit column called `IsCheap` do `SELECT * FROM STUFF WHERE IsCheap`, you have to do `WHERE IsCheap=1`.

The reason is simple, the data type is a bit, not a bool. True, it's basically the only use you'll put it to and it's implicitly converted by almost any data access framework, but it's still technically a bit with 0 or 1 rather than a bool with true or false. There's an obvious connection we can all see, but SQL wasn't written with this assumption in it so we have to provide the logic to convert true/false to 1/0.

Comment: I like this example too. Other vendors (MySQL/PostgreSQL) manage it

Answer (score 2):

The expression `price < 500` returns a **logical** value: TRUE, FALSE or UNKNOWN. It is not a **data** value, which is why you need to use a `CASE` expression to return a corresponding data value.

---

FWIW the Microsoft Access Database Engine does indeed treat the results of expressions as data values e.g. you can ask all kinds of wacky questions such as:

```
SELECT 1 = 1, 1 = NULL, 1 <> NULL, 1 IN (NULL)
  FROM Foo;
```

...and it will happily provide answers but of course this merely proves that Access does not implement the SQL language!

Answer (score 0):

I am not MSSQL person, but I ran into the same problem with Oracle. The trivial answer is, because Boolean is not a valid column type in those databases. Now, why they decided you don't need Booleans as values is anybody's guess.

@paxdiablo, that's so missing the point... The OP's example is just a minimal example. This is still simplistic but real-world example: Consider a People table, containing names and ages. You want to get all the people, but also want to know if they are underage. In both MySQL and PostgreSQL, you can write

```
SELECT name, age < 18 AS minor FROM people
```

Comment: The annoying thing is you *can* do CASE WHEN (intColumn) THEN truthValue ELSE falseValue END. So it can convert an int to a boolean, but not a boolean to a bit.

Comment: Indeed. I just checked TSQL docs - `<`'s result is Boolean (`TRUE` or `FALSE`, but such a data type is not even mentioned in "Data Types" article - but they have 1-bit integer! I hated Oracle, and now I hate MSSQL too (even not ever having worked with it)

Comment: @Graphain - No you can't. I just tried `SELECT CASE WHEN 1 THEN 't' ELSE 'f' END` and got `An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'THEN'.`